# awk: read user-name / base64-password, and print user-name / clear-password

Tags: awk

Input:

```
Stack T3ZlcmZsb3c=
```

Output:

```
Stack Overflow
```

Command that i want but does not working:

```
$ echo "Stack T3ZlcmZsb3c="|awk '{printf $1" "; printf $2|base64 -d; printf "\n"; }'
Stack 
/bin/sh: 1: 0: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

does this line help?

```
kent$  echo "Stack T3ZlcmZsb3c="|awk '{ "echo "$2"|base64 -d"|getline x;print $1,x}' 
Stack Overflow
```

Comment: As is, this didn't work for me.  By making a `cmd` out of the `getline` inputs and adding a `-n` to the `echo $2`, it does: `cmd= "echo -n "$2" |base64 -d"; cmd|getline x`...  Probably just different shell/system flavors.